# Rstudio-server on RHEL 6.5 pandoc error ifluatex.sty not found

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, rstudio-server, rhel6

OS: RHEL 6.5 x64
Rstudio-server Version 0.98.1062
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
knitr version 1.6

When attempting to knit an Rmarkdown file I get  a failure during the pandoc stage of the compilation:

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! LaTeX Error: File 'ifluatex.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
```

Tried the (9-hour-long) full manual LiveTeX install, just to be sure, and luatex is now installed, but there is still no ifluatex.sty to be found. How do I tell RStudioServer/knitr/pandoc where the installation directory for that file is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many thanks to [Homer White's blog](http://statistics.rainandrhino.org/blog/2014/08/27/r-studio-server-centos-pandoc-latex/) for sending me in the right direction. I'm more or less posting his answer verbatim, with minor modifications for RHEL 6.5 and 2014 LiveTex.

Even the full manual install had not solved the problem. Following Homer's advice, I downloaded from the internet a copy of ifluatex.sty
You can get it either [directly](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/matlabfragsupport/ifluatex.sty) or via wget from the CTAN archive.

```
wget http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/ifluatex.dtx
tex ifluatex.dtx
```

Copy the resulting file into the shared folder for your LaTeX Distribution. In RHEL 6/CentOS for the 2014 LiveTex distribution installed via install-tl this was:

```
/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek
```

Easy, right? Next step was to get the `framed` package:

```
wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/framed.zip
unzip framed.zip
```

This should create a folder in the download location. Now copy the entire folder to the Shared LiveTeX folder for LaTeX:

```
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex
```

Finally, let LiveTeX know it should update its library by running

```
texhash
```

PS: Note that I had root access. You might need it as well, of if you're a wheel user, prefix with sudo.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. But, as @Stuber mentions in the other answer, I had to set the permissions on `ifluatex.dtx`. It needs to be readable by others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is quick'n'dirty rpm spec file for those who do not want to install non-packaged files to /usr.

```
    Name: texlive-rstudio-addon-el6
    Version: 0.1
    Release:        1%{?dist}
    Summary: addon stylesheets for Rstudio pandoc
    Group:  Publishing
    License: LPPL1.3c+
    URL: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/
    Source0: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/ifluatex.dtx
    Source1: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/framed.zip
    BuildRequires:  texlive
    BuildRequires:  texlive-texmf
    BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)
    BuildArch:      noarch


    %description
    Couple styles addons which are required by RStudio pandoc when processing Rmarkdown documents

    %prep
    %setup -q -c -T
    cat %{SOURCE0} > ifluatex.dtx
    unzip %{SOURCE1}

    %build

    %install
    rm -rf %{buildroot} && mkdir -p %{buildroot}
    tex ifluatex.dtx
    mkdir -p %{buildroot}/%{_texmf_main}/tex/generic/oberdiek
    mkdir -p %{buildroot}/%{_texmf_main}/tex/latex/
    cp ifluatex.sty %{buildroot}/%{_texmf_main}/tex/generic/oberdiek
    cp -a framed %{buildroot}/%{_texmf_main}/tex/latex/

    %clean
    rm -rf %{buildroot}

    %post
    [ -x %{_bindir}/texconfig-sys ] && %{_bindir}/texconfig-sys rehash 2> /dev/null


    %files
    %defattr(-,root,root)
    %{_texmf_main}/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
    %{_texmf_main}/tex/latex/framed/*

    %doc
    %changelog
```

Answer (score 0):

For my fix root was needed and ifluatex and frame file permissions needed to be updated.